# Generics in static methods in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class Module {
  static register<T>(provider: Array<Provider>): ModuleWithProviders {
     return {
        ngModule: T, // error type is being used as value
        providers: provider
     };
}
```

I would like to have something like this `Module.register<AboutModule>([AboutService])` which tells the module and providers to be registered with that module but I am not sure how to do this using typescript generics
Could any one help me with this.

Also what should be the param type to accept only types instead of other types. Say I would like to have parameter that accepts only class types.

```
stats(list: ClassType){} // something like this
stats(list: any){} // currently im using this, how should I restrict param only to types.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not make it `(klass: typeof T, provider: Array<Provider>)`? Then you call it `.register(AboutModule, [AboutService])` and `T` is inferred from the first parameter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe when i use klass: typeof T its throwing error only referred as type but used as value

Comment: Well you also need `ngModule: klass`, not `T`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  static register<T>(klass: typeof T, provider: Array<Provider>): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
        ngModule: klass,
        providers: provider
      };
    } but im still getting the error. Iam getting this error at kclass: typeof T line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `Class` type:

```
export type Abstract<T = any> = Function & { prototype: T };

export type Instantiable<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export type Class<T = any> = Abstract<T> | Instantiable<T>;
```

Source: https://github.com/kaiu-lab/serializer/blob/master/src/class.ts

And ask for an array of classes as parameters.

Types can't be used inside the method itself, this can't be done in typescript at all, because you can't get the class of a type at runtime.

Feel free to explore the code in the github I linked, we has this exact issue and solved it using this custom class type.